# Nginx redirect domain to subdomain url with persist url

Tags: redirect, nginx

We have a ruby application serving through passenger+nginx on url like abc.xyz.com.
Now we want to point/redirect **xyz.com** to **abc.xyz.com/client/page**.
Below is tried code

```
server {
    server_name xyz.com;
    location  / {
         return 301 $scheme://abc.xyz.com/client/page;
    }
}
```

But in browser URL it shows abc.xyz.com/client/page. We want the xyz.com.

Comment: Isn't that exactly, what the nginx asks the browser to do? Instead of xyz.com fetching data from abc.xyz.com/client/page - or did I not get the point of the question? Redirect is a client action to fulfill, right?

Comment: @Dilettant Yes,  xyz.com should fetch data from abc.xyz.com/client/page .

Comment: You need a reverse proxy not a redirect. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) for more.

Comment: @RichardSmith Could you please post sample configuration according to above situation.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried below conf but it showing abc.xyz.com landing page :
       upstream mywebapp1 {
        ip_hash;
        server 10.10.10.1
        server 10.10.10.2;
    }
 
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name xyz.com;
       location / {
       proxy_pass http://mywebapp1/client/page/;
       proxy_redirect          default;
       }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution and working fine on single Nginx server:

Added server name entry as below to the existing,

```
server_name abc.xyz.com xyz.com;
```

in server block added below

```
    if ($host = xyz.com)
    {
rewrite ^/$ $scheme://$host/client/page/;
}
```

But now big work remaining, I need to change this config according to proxy_pass.